# Mongoose queries chain

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model and can do chaining queries like find(), limit(), skip().
The question is how can I apply limit or skip function to Model.find() output, if output (returning value) does not contain limit function?

For example this code works:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const password = encodeURIComponent("*****");
const username = encodeURIComponent("*****");

async function main() {

    await mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.e5rojbd.mongodb.net/test?ssl=true&retryWrites=true&w=majority`);
    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    });
    const Name = mongoose.model('names', userSchema);
    const limitedNames = Name.find().limit(2).skip(1);
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(limitedNames)))
    // output is [ 'constructor', '_queryMiddleware' ]
}
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But how is it possible?

Comment: It seems like you are not execute the query. Try apply `await` (`await Name.find().limit(2).skip(1)`) or [`.exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.exec()) to return a promise.

Comment: Do you need an explanation of how it's possible or is your question that it doesn't work and you want it to work?

Answer (score 1):

`.limit` and `.skip` methods do not "chain" on the find query, they modify the command before it is sent to the server.

`Model.find()` returns a query object, which is a type of promise.  When `await` or `.exec` is used with that object, a [find](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/find/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.find) database command is sent to the mongod server.

The `limit`, `skip`, and `sort` methods populate the corresponding field in the query object, which are then included with the command sent to the server when `await` or `exec` are used.

Try

```
const limitedNames = await Name.find().limit(2).skip(1)
```